# Printing awk output in same line after grep

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, printf

I have a very crude script getinfo.sh that gets me information from all files with name FILENAME1 and FILENAME2 in all subfolders and the path of the subfolder. The awk result should only pick the nth line from FILENAME2 if the script is called with *"getinfo.sh n"*. I want all the info printed in one line!

The problem is that if i use print instead of printf the info is written to a new line but my script works. If i use printf i can see the last bit of the awk command in the command propt after the script ist done, but it is not paset after the grep command in the same line. All in all the complete line would be pretty long, but that is intentionally. Would you be willing to tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
while read -r fname ;
do
    pushd $(dirname "${fname}") > /dev/null
    printf '%q' "${PWD##*/}"
    grep 'Search_term ' FILENAME1 | tail -1
    awk '{ if(NR==n) printf "%s",$0 }' n=$1 $2 FILENAME2
    popd > /dev/null
done < <(find . -type f -name 'FILENAME1')
```

I would also be happy to grep the nth line if this is easier?

**SOLUTION:**

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
while read -r fname ;
do
    pushd $(dirname "${fname}") > /dev/null
   {
     printf '%q' "${PWD##*/}"
     grep 'Search_term' FILENAME1 | tail -1
   } | tr -d '\n'

   if [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2>/dev/null
   then
        awk '{ if(NR==n) printf "%s",$0 }' n="$1" FILENAME2
   fi

    printf "\n"
    popd > /dev/null
done < <(find . -type f -name 'FILENAME1')
```

Comment: I don't understand you, you mean you want `grep 'Search_term ' FILENAME1 | awk 'NR==n' n=$1` ?

Comment: Hi the awk command runs on a seperate file named FILENAME2 which is also in each subfolder. So i want the output of the command `grep 'Search_term ' FILENAME1 | tail -1` which searches for the string `Search_term` and prints the rest of the line to appear in the same line as the command `awk '{ if(NR==n) printf "%s",$0 }' n=$1 $2 FILENAME2`. If i used `awk '{ if(NR==n) print $0 }' n=$1 $2 FILENAME2` it works but the output appears in a new line.

Comment: You want the output of the command `awk ...` to appear on the same line as the output of the `grep....` ? You want to remove newlines from one of the commands? You mean `tr -d '\n'` ?

Comment: If if i try this, everything is printed in one line. I want the output of `printf '%q' "${PWD##*/}"` and `grep 'Search_term ' FILENAME1 | tail -1` and `awk '{ if(NR==n) printf "%s",$0 }' n=$1 $2 FILENAME2` to be printed in one line for each time the loop runs. In each iteration a new line should be used. I also want that this happens independently if i pass the script a number for the awk command or not. If i do not pass a number the awk command should be omited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made it clearer in the comments.

> I want the output of printf '%q' "${PWD##*/}" and grep 'Search_term ' FILENAME1 | tail -1 and awk '{ if(NR==n) printf "%s",$0 }' n=$1 $2 FILENAME2 to be printed in one line

So first, we have three commands, that each print a single line of output. As the commands do not matter, let's wrap them in functions to simplify the answer:

```
cmd1() { printf '%q\n' "${PWD##*/}"; }
cmd2() { grep .... ; }
cmd3() { awk ....; }
```

To print them without newlines between them, we can:

1. Use a command substitution, which removes trailing empty newlines. With some printf:

   ```
   printf "%s%s%s\n" "$(cmd1)" "$(cmd2)" "$(cmd3)"
   ```

   or some echo:

   ```
   echo "$(cmd1) $(cmd2) $(cmd3)"
   ```

   or append to a variable:

   ```
   str="$(cmd1)"
   str+=" $(cmd2)"
   str+=" $(cmd3)"
   printf" %s\n" "$str"
   ```

   and so on.
2. We can remove newlines from the stream, using `tr -d '\n'`:

   ```
   {
        cmd1
        cmd2
        cmd3
   } | tr -d '\n'
   echo # newlines were removed, so add one to the end.
   ```

   or we can also remove the newlines only from the first `n-1` commands, but I think this is less readable:

   ```
   {
      cmd1
      cmd2
   } | tr -d'\n'
   cmd3 # the trailing newline will be added by cmd3
   ```

> If i do not pass a number the awk command should be omited.

I see that your `awk` command expands both `$1` and `$2`, and i see only `$1` to be passed as the `n=$1` environment variable to `awk`. I don't know what is `$2`. You can write if-s on the value of `$#` the number of arguments:

```
if (($# == 2)); then
    awk '{ if(NR==n) printf "%s",$0 }' n="$1" "$2" FILENAME2
fi
```

and similar for each case you want to handle. Remember about proper quoting.

Comment: Thanks  allot !!! i was able to construct a solution based on your commen which at least works the way i want it. I hope is not incorect.

Answer (score 1):

Your command shows the unused parameter `$2`, I deleted that one.
You can add a newline at the end of the `awk` using the `END` block, but you also want an extra newline when you call your script without a line number. `echo` will do.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
while read -r fname ;
do
   pushd $(dirname "${fname}") > /dev/null
   # Add result of grep in same printf statement
   printf '%s %s' "${PWD##*/}" "$(grep 'Search_term ' FILENAME1 | tail -1)"
   if (( $# -eq 1 )); then
      # use $1 as an awk variable, number n
      # use $2 as a different file to read from
      awk -v n=$1 '{ if(NR==n) printf "%s ",$0 }' FILENAME2
   fi
   # Add line-ending
   echo
   popd > /dev/null
done < <(find . -type f -name 'FILENAME1')
```

Comment: Hi
thanks alot. Your solution is way better than what i constrcuted based on the above comment. Is it possible, to use the parameter `$2` as FILENAME2 but preset it to a string if no parameter is given?

Comment: Use `echo ${2:-FILENAME2}` When you want the first parameter when the linenumber is not given, you need additional logic when only one parameter is given.